# Access multiple databases in Mule ESB

Tags: jdbc, groovy, mule

I have a Mule flow that needs to connect to a user-specified database, as opposed to a static datasource configured into the flow.

I've got the connection parameters - URL, user, etc - and I'm trying to write a simple block of Groovy script to establish a connection to the target database using code like this:

```
sql = Sql.newInstance(“jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB", “root”, “pass”, “com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

I've tried several variations of Sql.newInstance, but no matter what I've tried, I'm getting
**`javax.script.ScriptException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306`**.

The MySQL driver (mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar) is included in my Mule project (I see it as a “Referenced Library”). I've tried placing the Jar file in several places as recommended by other posters, but no change.

I don't believe this is a missing Jar file issue. If I declare a static datasource in my Mule project, code like this works perfectly:

```
JdbcConnector jdbcConnector = (JdbcConnector) muleContext.getRegistry().lookupConnector("MyDB");
DataSource datasource = (DataSource) jdbcConnector.getDataSource();
Connection connection = (Connection) datasource.getConnection();
sql.setConnection(connection);
```

I have MuleStudio 3.5.0 Build 201312201424, but the behavior seems to be the same on the prior release.

My questions:

1. Is there some magic to getting Sql.newInstance() to work in Groovy?
2. Is there a better way to dynamically create a JDBC connection?

Comment: Have you tried to do the same with Mule standalone, outside MuleStudio?

Comment: Seems to give the same result both in MuleStudio and on a standalone (CE) runtime. In MuleStudio, I've tried building for both EE and CE runtimes and I'm having the same problem either way.

Comment: did you eventually solve this problem? I have the same issue and I am looking around for solutions that do not involve creating the jdbc connection statically on the mule config

Comment: Yes - we tried many approaches, but eventually we wrote what Mule sees as a custom JDBC driver to handle these issues. This gave us a way to alter the connection parameters (and driver names, etc) based on context - works like a champ, within limits.